# How to attach GestureDetector to a ListPreference?

Tags: android, listpreference, gesturedetector

The challenge of attaching a [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) to a [ListPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html) is 2-fold:

1. Getting a handle to a ListPreference that's only defined in a preferences.xml (i.e. not instantiated in Java code).
2. ListPreference is neither a View nor Activity subclass.

Is it possible at all to attach a [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) to a [ListPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html)?

If so, how would one go about this? Where would I write the code to instantiate GestureDetector and implement the listener?

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the main goal with this implementation - what is the expected result and what the `GestureDetector` is going to be used for?

Comment: @g00dy All I want from it at this point is detect a long-press on any item on the list (and of course return the index of the item that was long-pressed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I didn't quite catch the question correctly, the answer is probably simpler than you might think. The source code for `ListPreferece` teaches that it's little more than a wrapper around an `AlertDialog` that displays its various options in a `ListView`. Now, `AlertDialog` actually allows you to get a handle on the `ListView` it wraps, which is probably all you need.

In one of the comments you indicated that, at this stage, all you're interested in is detecting a long-press on any item in the list. So rather than answering that by attaching a `GestureDetector`, I'll simply use an `OnItemLongClickListener`.

```
public class ListPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceClickListener {

    private ListPreference mListPreference;

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.list_prefs);

        mListPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("pref_list");
        mListPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog) mListPreference.getDialog();
        dialog.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long click on index " + position + ": " 
                        + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

}
```

The result (which the toast in the long-click displaying):

[image]

With a reference to the `ListView`, you could also attach an `OnTouchListener`, `GestureDetector` etc. Up to you to go from here.

Comment: Yes, you caught the question correctly. :-)  +1, accepting & rewarding the bonus. Now... is there any chance that the cast to `(AlertDialog)` will **not** work in some Android version/flavor/distro/customization?

Comment: @scatmoi: The cast should be safe for anything that extends from `DialogPreference`, because that enforces its extending classes to build the `Dialog` using `onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder)`. I had a quick look, and `ListPreference` absides this by contract down to at least Android 1.5 (Cupcake). As a matter of fact, `ListPreference` has hardly changed throughout the years...  Anyways, just for sanity, it wouldn't hurt to add an `instanceof` check before the cast. :)

Answer (score 1):

As @TronicZomB suggested, this isn't *directly* possible.

You can work around this by creating your own ListPreference derived class, getting its view in the inherited onBindDialogView().

Remember however that the latter is tricky because onBindDialogView() is only called if onCreateDialogView() doesn't return null, and this can happen only if you create your own custom view for YourListPreference.

The recommended way to do this is to [build a custom Preference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Custom).

Once you have done that, you have a reference to YourListPreference's view, which is mandatory for attaching GestureDetector because one of the steps requires setOnTouchListener() on the view.

Comment: Your method may work but it is too cumbersome. @MH.'s approach is more elegant (but I don't know if it is guaranteed to be compatible with future Android versions).

Answer (score 0):

I have set a GestrueDetector to a ScrollView using `setOnTouchListener` previously and searched for a similar method for ListPreference, however since the ListPreference does not contain such a method, I do not believe this will be possible.

Comment: The crux of the challenge here is that `ListPreference` **is** a view, but it isn't defined in a layout XML and thus can't be accessed via [findViewById()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17192066/1088880). Or can it? I am beginning to think that the only way around this is to define & use a subclass of ListPreference, then in its `onCreate()`, [setOnTouchListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener(android.view.View.OnTouchListener)) to it.

Comment: You might be able to do a `getView().setOnTouchListener()`. Not sure how exactly though.