# How to setOnTouchListener() on a ListPreference?

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener, preferenceactivity, listpreference

Handling onTouchEvent on a view is straightforward as every view has the setOnTouchListener() method to do just that.

Alas, although [ListPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html) is a view, it isn't defined in a layout XML, and thus can't be accessed via findViewById(). So... I don't seem to figure out how to setOnTouchListener() for it.

My idea was to get a reference to it in PreferenceActivity's onCreate(), then getDialog().[getCurrentFocus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#getCurrentFocus%28%29) but at that particular moment in time, it has no focus and not even a dialog (getDialog() returns null, confirmed).

Any idea how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener)` for the shared preferences, if you are interested in all the preferences, or `.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(listener)` if you only want to know the changes on one item. You will be notified when the preference is changed.

Comment: I am afraid that wouldn't cut it for me. I am not really interested in only knowing when a preference has changed (I am already implementing it BTW). What I really want is to [attach a GestureDetector](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17181083/1088880) to a ListPreference. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to do something like `findViewById(android.R.id.list)` on the preference view?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that because a ListPreference is not a view. It *is* defined in an XML, but not a layout XML. Am I out of luck?

Comment: you define it inside an xml but you use it from a fragment or from an activity. The listPreference is used to create a view after that so in the end it will be a view.

Comment: Yes, but what id to use for `findViewById()`? AFAIK, a ListPreference has no id, because it's **not** defined in a layout XML. Can you actually point to code that gets the id of a ListPreference?

Comment: if you are using the listPreference inside a `PreferenceActivity` use `findViewById(android.R.id.list)`, if you are inside a fragment, inside the method `onViewCreated()`, you can do `view.findViewById(android.R.id.list)`

Comment: `android.R.id.list` is the ID for the entire PreferenceActivity view, not the `ListPreference`. Also note that a PreferenceActivity could have more than one `ListPreference`s... Lastly, if all I really wanted is the PreferenceActivity view, there is already [PreferenceActivity.getListView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView())