# onBindDialogView not called - Why?

Tags: android, listpreference, dialog-preference

I am trying to implement a subclass of ListPreference and while its constructor **is** being called (upon displaying it), its overriden onBindDialogView isn't.

```
  public MyListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    Log.v(TAG, "MyListPreference constructed.");
  }


  @Override
  protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
    super.onBindDialogView(view);
    Log.v(TAG, "onBindDialogView called");    
  }
```

Why is this happening? What am I missing?

**Update**: I planted a log message in [onCreateDialogView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html#onCreateDialogView%28%29) and it **is** being called, too.

It is only [onBindDialogView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html#onBindDialogView%28android.view.View%29) that is **not** being called.

Why? What are the conditions for this callback to be invoked?

Comment: What are you trying to do in `onBindDialogView()`?

Comment: @shoerat I am trying to [setOnTouchListener() on a ListPreference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17192066).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does your `onCreateDialogView()` return? `onBindDialogView()` is called only if you return a non-null custom view from in there. Also, `onBindDialogView()` is only called when you actually show the preference. Ref: [Source code of DialogPreference](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/preference/DialogPreference.java). In particular, see `showDialog()` method

If you just return the super implementation from your `onCreateDialogView()`, I suspect it returns `null`.

Comment: My `onCreateDialogView()` returns what its `super.onCreateDialogView()` returns: **null**. How do I make it return non-null without changing the original ListPreference view/layout? I don't really want to change anything in the view/layout. All I really want is get a handle/reference to the original ListPreference **view**. Is this at all possible? If so, how? +1 & thanks for now.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a public API to get a handle to the `ListView` that is housed within a `ListPreference`. You do have a `DialogPreference#getDialog()` - which you can cast to `AlertDialog()`, and from there you can do a `getListView()` but this depends on a lot of implementation details and I wouldn't recommend it. I'd rather suggest you to create a custom `Preference` where you have full control over the content view.

Comment: Actually, see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181083/how-to-attach-gesturedetector-to-a-listpreference#comment25182806_17351742), but you answered my question so well, so accepting + bounty.

Comment: How do you get hold of all of the dialog, and set the direction of it (for example, in order to support it being RTL ) ?